# Connecting to World Air Quality Index (waqi.info) via AT commands

Tags: json, tcp, arduino, esp8266, at-command

this is my first post on stackoverflow so please be patient with me.
I'm working on an Air Quality Project with an Arduino and need an online AQI for that to compare it to my own measurements. I got an ESP8266 ESP-01S which connects to the Internet and I already gathered information from other websites, so everything works fine. But I just can't get to connect it to the waqi.info website. For that purpose I'm using the API, generated my own token and tried to connect to http://api.waqi.info/feed/shanghai/?token=demo with my token inserted instead of "demo". I'm doing this by AT commands (because that's the only way I can use the ESP8266).

So here's my code, a few eplanations:

1. AT is the ESP8266 so with AT.println(...) I'm sending the command to the ESP8266:
2. aqiIP is https://api.waqi.info
3. I'm really not that much into TCP connections, but I looked up the ports, 80 is for HTTP and 443 is for HTTPS (and since it's https, I assumed maybe I needed this?), but I also tried the latter, it didn't change anything. Also I tried to leave out the https part and started directly with api.waqi..., still no result, always the same message (see end of post)

   ```
     String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=1,\"TCP\",\"";
     cmd += aqiIP;
     cmd += "\",80";
     AT.println(cmd);
     testString = AT.readString(); //for testing if data was received
     Serial.println(testString);
     delay(2000);
     if (AT.find("Error")) {
       return;
       Serial.println("NO TCB CONNECTION");
     }
     cmd = "GET /feed/@6132/?token=" + aqiKey;
     cmd += "\r\n";
     AT.print("AT+CIPSEND=1,");
     AT.println(cmd.length());
           if (AT.find(">")) {
       AT.print(cmd);
       testString = AT.readString(); //for testing if data was received
       Serial.println(testString);
       while (!AT.find("\"aqi\":")) {} // find the part we are interested in.
       while (true) {
         if (AT.available()) {
           char c = AT.read();
           if (c == ',') break;
           aqi += c;
         }
       }
       Serial.println("AQI: ");
       Serial.println(aqi);
     }
   ```

When I use the api.waqi.info link with my token it works perfectly, I can see the JSON file with all the parameters, but I just can't connect to it. I already used the TCP connection through API of several other websites, like api.openweathermap.org, which website looks exactly same (also with the JSON file), but when I used the exact same procedure on the AQI, it just doesn't work.
After CIPSTART it reads CONNECT, then after CIPSEND with the GET request it reads SEND OK (which usually means everything worked fine) but then I get this message:

*+IPD,1,117:JP1N: Oooopps... Are you looking for waqi.info or eadalabs.com1,CLOSED*

and no information on the AQI.

What am I doing wrong here? As I mentioned, with openweathermaps it worked perfectly fine and I get the JSON file printed on my Serial monitor and I used nearly the exact same code, I just changed the URLs.

Any advices would be appreciated, here's the doc for the WAQI API:
https://aqicn.org/api/ and https://aqicn.org/json-api/doc/

Comment: if aqiIP = "https://api.waqi.info" then cmd += "\",443"; (the https port). On top of that is the X509 certificate associated with "https://api.waqi.info" which has to be either verified or ignored. When I put "https://api.waqi.info" into a browser it doesn't work due to this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/secure-connection-failed-firefox-did-not-connect

Comment: thanks @codebrane but when I try port 443 I get this answer: +IPD,1,264: *<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>*

Comment: yes HTTPS on 443 requires encryption using a certificate by the client.

Comment: send a valid HTTP request with a Host header

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, really appreciate it, but I'm new to this whole thing so what exactly do I have to do? How can I send a request with a Host header? @Juraj

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Message_format

Comment: For everybody interested or having the same problem, I fixed it by adding more lines to the GET command: ```cmd = "GET /feed/munich/?token=" + aqiKey;
  cmd += " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  cmd += "Host: api.waqi.info\r\n";
  cmd += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";``` 

I don't really know what i exactly worked, but it does

Comment: @DisposableGuy the HTTP request, without the bytes you added, was wrongly formatted.